# How can I use OpenAI API in my Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, openai-api

I'm trying to integrate OpenAI into my Telegram Bot. but I can't download the API with Maven

I tried to insert the Maven section into my pom.xml file, but I get an error

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.theokanning.openai-gpt3-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>       
</dependency>
```

and I tried this

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>ai.openai</groupId>
  <artifactId>openai-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

ERROR:
Could not find artifact ai.openai:openai-api:pom:1.0.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

maybe this link could help: https://github.com/TheoKanning/openai-java

Comment: The latest version of com.theokanning.openai-gpt3-java:client is [0.11.1](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.theokanning.openai-gpt3-java/client/0.11.1), not 1.0.0. There is no ai.openai:openai-api (at least, not on Maven Central), why do you think such an artifact exists?

Comment: Yes, sorry. that still doesn't work with 0.11.1 version

Comment: @gitdogee Why do you think it should work? Where did you get the name of the artifact from?

Comment: @J Fabian Meier Chat GPT